# How to create a new edge using existing nodelabel/headlabel in graphviz/dotEditor without duplicating a new one

Tags: graphviz, dot, dotfiles

```
digraph G {
   "DUT0" [label="DUT0"];  "DUT1" [label="DUT1"];
   "DUT0" -> "DUT1"  [headlabel="1", taillabel="2"];
   "DUT1" -> "DUT1"  [taillabel="1", headlabel="3"];
}
```

I am using the below script in graphviz dotEditor to create my graph.

The script mentioned above creates below diagram.

[image]

My requirement is: Instead of creating a new taillabel(1) on node DUT1(Edge from 1-->3) , it should use the same existing one.

How can I achieve this? Please help, Thanks in advance.

Adding the resulting image which is required.
[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Could you rephrase your request.  I've come up with multiple interpretations of what you are after.  Specifically, are you trying to simplify your input or modify the resulting image?

Comment: Sure @sroush. I will try to explain it better.

The node DUT1 , have a port 1 , which is connected to port 2 of DUT0 and port3 of its own.  So instead of having a duplicate port 1 on DUT1,  it should use the same port 1. what changes should i make in my dot script to achieve this.

Adding the result image which i require in the original question.

Thanks for the response.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Probably not possible, but maybe you should have a look at the node placements (based on wind directions, as you also indicate in your hand drawing) and leave one of the labels like:

```
digraph G {
  "DUT0" -> "DUT1" [headlabel="1", taillabel="2"];
  "DUT1":n -> "DUT1" [ headlabel="3"];
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Albert